# How To Align a Control to the Text of a Radio Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, alignment

Is there a way in WPF to align a control with the beginning of the text in a radio button above it without simply using margins? In the example below, I have a radio button in the 1st row and a textblock in the row directly below it. I want the text in the textblock to line up with the text in the radiobutton.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why using margins is not sufficient?

Comment: I'm using a custom styled radio button. So I'd prefer it to still be lined up even if I update the style of the radio button

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the text of the radio button from the button itself.

Something like this should work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Location" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="hahah" />
</Grid>
```

It is a pretty verbose solution for such a small task, but they will always be aligned.

Comment: True that would work. Although I would lose the ability to select the radio button by clicking the text.

Comment: @user2481095 You can accommodate for that in various ways, none that are what I'd consider clean, but do-able.  Perhaps make the text a style-less `ToggleButton` or `RadioButton` without a "button" part.  Then bind it to the `RadioButton.IsChecked`.  Again, pretty hacky, but it will work.

Comment: @user2481095 You can set `IsHitTestVisible = false`